# Can XP load pre-installation drivers from anywhere other than a floppy?

Tags: windows-xp, raid, floppy

I'm planning to install XP Pro on a new machine with a motherboard that supports RAID. The partition XP will run from will be on RAID 1. To set this up you normally enter a floppy disk with the motherboard RAID driver at the beginning of the XP installation.

I'd prefer if the new machine didn't have a floppy drive. It's pretty much pointless now. But this poses the problem of loading the RAID driver. Can XP read this driver from somewhere else (maybe USB) or will I have to install a floppy drive just for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them directly on the CD unsing nLite (great tool to customize installation)! That's what I did for my SATA controller

[Documentation](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2008/02/08/how-to-integrate-floppy-sata-raid-driver-into-windows-xp-cd/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use nLite to add the appropriate driver to a copy of your install CD, then boot and let Windows find the driver by itself.

http://www.nliteos.com

Of course, a floppy drive is so cheap that buying one is probably the most reasonable option. But probably not as fun though ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Without a floppy drive you have 4 choices:

1. install a floppy drive
2. use an external usb floppy drive **IF** the bios has an option to enable legacy support for usb
3. slipstream the drivers using program like nLite
4. manually create an XP install cd with the needed drivers

See this Microsoft support [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916196/en-us) to find out which USB floppy drives are supported by XP.

Answer (score 1):

some (newer) Mainboards support an USB-Stick connected on Startup
 so if you are promted "for thrid-Party drivers" you can access the USB-Drive.

it will work when the BIOS has an Option to Boot from USB-Devices, because it will check for attached usb-devices during the start