# Unable to install Windows XP - Hard Disks Not Found

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, installation, troubleshooting

I use a DVD windows installer with automatic detect my driver. When I use it, it works normally. but when installer finishes scanning the disc, I encountered this error:

> Set up did not find any hard disk drives installed in your computer. Make sure any hard disk drives are powered on and properly connected to your computer and that any disk related hardware configuration is correct. This may involve running a manufacturer supplied diagnostic or setup program. Set up can't continue. To quit setup press F3.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to load your disk controller/sata drivers since Windows XP is not shipped with any AHCI-compliant hard disk driver.

Have a look at this KB for a How-To: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314859

If you do not own a floppy drive you can integrate your driver into the setup disk. This involves burning a slightly modified installation disk. A guide can be found here:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Install-Windows-XP-On-SATA-Without-a-Floppy-F6-47807.shtml

Or have a look at this SU: [Can XP load pre-installation drivers from anywhere other than a floppy?](https://superuser.com/questions/107066/can-xp-load-pre-installation-drivers-from-anywhere-other-than-a-floppy)

Answer (score 1):

Your harddrive is using a sata connection.  This was not supported in XP.  You will need to slipstream your installation disk so that the sata drivers are available at the installation time.

You can accomplish this via [nLite](http://home.midmaine.com/~nlite/nlite/nLite-1.4.9.1.installer.exe).

Answer (score 0):

This means the installer could not find a hard drive. Make sure you have a hard drive connected to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for had to guess version you meant, I'm still not sure about this due to lack of info.

if you are installing **windows xp** onto a computer with acpi-enabled or raid-ed harddrive, maybe you need some third-party driver.

on win7 it may be better. i was not asked for acpi controller driver during installing win7.

Comment: "F3" is most likely to be Windows XP, no need to apologize ;-).